# no traffic is captured when using scapy

Tags: python, networking, dhcp, scapy

I'm trying to create a simple script causing a DHCP server to run out of addresses.
the network consists of two machines both virtual and running CentOS, who seems to be communicating - ICMP traffic works fine (packet are captured in wireshark).

I'm running the following python script:

```
from scapy.all import *

conf.checkIPaddr = False
dhcp_discover =  Ether(src=RandMAC(),dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="255.255.255.255")/UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(chaddr=RandString(12,'112233445566'))/DHCP(options=[("message-type","discover"),"end"])
sendp(dhcp_discover,loop=1)
```

When I'm running the script no traffic is being captured, both outgoing, on the client, and ingoing on the server.

Anyone have a lead for the source of the problem?

Comment: Did you run your script with root rights? Is SELinux in permissive state?

Comment: yes to both of the questions

Comment: You don't specify the interface to use at any point. It might just be using `lo`. Try setting the `iface` parameter to `sendp`.